# Angular CLI project does not find component from ng2-spin-kit

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I create a new angular-cli (version 1.0.5) project and add the npm module [ng2-spin-kit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-spin-kit) (version 1.3.0). Then I modify the files **src/app/app.module.ts** and **src/app/app.component.html** in order to test the component **WaveComponent**.

Build and starting server (`ng serve`) works without problems. But starting the app in the browser leads to this startup failure:

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'WaveComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:43136:34)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:56868:40
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:56850:54)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:68126:70)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:68099:36)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:68028:37)
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6052:25)
    at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:6038:21)
    at Object.171 (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:19:124)
```

Full project available in:
https://github.com/ManfredSteiner/ng2-cli-test-spin-kit

The WaveComponent sources are available when following to source (in vscode). Also the bundles contains this component.

Any ideas what's going wrong? What I can check to find the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it seems that you have version conflict with the @angular packages (common, compiler, platform-browser, etc. Check ng2-spin-kit dependencies on npm).

Ng2-spin-kit uses version 2 and your project uses version 4.

I tried to add ng2-spin-kit to a cli project which uses version 2 from those libraries and spinners work like a charm.

I do not have a solution for you if you insist to angular version 4, but if version 2 is okay than:

The way I could make this work was to :

1. update your package.json
2. cleared node-modules folder (if already exist)
3. npm install
4. npm install ng2-spin-kit --save

   ```
   {
     "name": "ng2-cli-test-spin-kit",
     "version": "0.0.0",
     "license": "MIT",
     "scripts": {
       "ng": "ng",
       "start": "ng serve",
       "build": "ng build",
       "test": "ng test",
       "lint": "ng lint",
       "e2e": "ng e2e"
     },
     "private": true,
     "dependencies": {
       "@angular/common": "^2.4.10",
       "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.10",
       "@angular/core": "^2.4.10",
       "@angular/forms": "^2.4.10",
       "@angular/http": "^2.4.10",
       "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.10",
       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.10",
       "@angular/router": "^3.4.10",
       "core-js": "^2.4.1",
       "ng2-spin-kit": "^1.3.0",
       "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
       "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
     },
     "devDependencies": {
       "@angular/cli": "~1.1.0",
       "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.10",
       "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
       "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
       "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
       "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
       "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
       "karma": "~1.4.1",
       "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
       "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
       "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
       "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
       "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
       "protractor": "~5.1.0",
       "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
       "tslint": "~4.5.0",
       "typescript": "~2.3.2"
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Sounds good, I tried to reproduce it, using your package.json. But all the time **npm install** downloads the latest angular version 4.x.x. I have also removed the ^ on the versions, without change. Any ideas what's going wrong if always the latest version is downloaded?

Comment: I removed the file `package-lock.json` and the directory `node_modules`. Then **npm install** downloads Angular 2 version 2.4. With this version ng2-spin-kit works. Thank you for your effort. I will create a bug-issue in the git-repository of ng2-spin-kit.